# How do I install additional modules when building an Apache RPM?

Tags: compiling, rpm

We've been compiling and installing Apache under `/usr/local/apache2` and in turn would tar the folder up to distribute to our other servers. I would like to convert this into an RPM package for easier maintenance. I'll be using `fpm` to handle the package creation, but I'm running into an issue when including additional modules.

Once the `make install` completes, we have a couple of additional modules to compile and install using `apxs`. For example, to install `mod_qos` we would run the following command once the package is uncompressed.

`/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs PATH_TO_MOD_OAS_DIRECTORY`

That installs the `mod_qos.so` file into Apache's module directory. But let's say my `make install` turns into `make install DESTDIR=/opt/buildbot` I mean I really don't want to install Apache on my build server. I want to stage it so that i can use `fpm` to create the rpm package.